# Flutter BLE app to blink an led as many times the input

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, utf-8, bluetooth-lowenergy

My intention is to build a Flutter BLE application to blink an led as many times the number given as user input. I am using flutter_blue plugin( https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue). Also, I’ve imported ‘dart:convert’ for the utf8 conversion. I am getting the user input with `TextEditingController()`. Here is a piece of my code.

```
BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic;
final _writeController = TextEditingController();
TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        controller: _writeController,
        ),
FlatButton(
        child: Text("Send"),
        onPressed: () {
        characteristic.write(utf8.encode(_writeController.value.text));
        Navigator.pop(context);
           },
        ),
```

But, the led is blinking corresponding `ASCII` value times the user input. For example, when the user input is 5, the led is blinking 53 times. Please, help me get through this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make `keyboardType: TextInputType.number` if all you expect is numbers.

Then

```
characteristic.write([int.parse(_writeController.text)]);
```